# Difference between ary[start, length] and ary[range] in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]
```

What is the difference between these two statements?

```
a[1,3]                #=> [ "b", "c", "d" ]
```

vs

```
a[1..3]               #=> [ "b", "c", "d" ]
```

Comment: Since `a[1..3] == a[1,3] => true` (more generally, `a(n..m) == a(n,n-m+1) => true`), there is no difference, but one may be more convenient to use in particular situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one takes three indices starting at index `1`. The second one takes indices between `1` and  `3`.

Answer (score 2):

With range, you can use negative numbers as `Array` index

```
 a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ] 

 > a[1,-1]
 #=> nil 

 > a[1..-1]
 #=> ["b", "c", "d", "e"]

 > a[1..-2]
 #=> ["b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: The semantics are different, negative values are just one side of it... `a[2,4] != a[2..4]`

Comment: @UriAgassi Yes! realized that after reading Sawa's answer so many times :)